# Dividir al presionar un boton y que el input cambie en javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo un problema quiero un formulario con un input donde yo inserto una cantidad supongamos 100 y que esta cantidad al yo presionar en mi boton me la divida entre 4 modificando el valor del input sin tener que utilizar otros input pero al hacerlo me aparecen las letras NaN este error me gustaria si alguien me podria ayudar para saber que hago mal. Este es mi codigo.
Muchas gracias ^^

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="num1">
<br>
<button value="divisiones" onClick="Dividir()">Dividir</button>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function Dividir()
{
var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value = (num1/4);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hazlo en dos pasos:

```
  function Dividir() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value
    document.getElementById("num1").value = (num1 / 4);
  }
```

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="num1">
    <br>
    <button value="divisiones" onClick="Dividir()">Dividir</button>
  </body>

</html>
<script>
  function Dividir() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value
    document.getElementById("num1").value = (num1 / 4);
  }
</script>
```

Aunque no tiene mucho sentido, al menos para mi, que uses el mismo campo del input para mostrar el resultado.